# Access n:th element of every list in list of lists

Tags: python, list, nlp, tuples

I have a problem in python and one step I need to do is to access the second element of every list in a list of lists. The list is:

```
[(0, 'Gallery', 'PROPN', 'nsubj'), (1, 'unveils', 'VERB', 'root'), (2, 'interactive', 'ADJ', 'amod')]

[(0, 'A', 'DET' 'det'), (1 'Christmas' , 'PROPN', 'compound'), (2, 'tree' ,'NOUN', 'nsubjpass')]
```

The list goes on like that with different sentences for each list.

What I am trying to do is access the third (index 2) element of every list of every tuple. So from the first list, I want to get:

1. PROPN (from 'Gallery')
2. VERB (from 'unveils')
3. ADJ (from 'interactive')

And from the second list I want to get:

1. DET (from 'A')
2. PROPN (from 'Christmas')
3. NOUN (from 'nsubjpass)

What I've tried to do is this:

```
for word in list:
      print(list[word[0]][2])
```

But that only outputs the second element from the first list. I tried creating another foor-loop but that didn't work, I suspect I did it wrong but I'm not sure how to solve it

Help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `[sub_list[2] for sub_list in my_list]`

Comment: How would I go about implementing that?
I tried:

`for sub_list in sent_pred:
      print(sub_list[2])`

But that only printed the third word of the first sentence
@Moinuddin Quadri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are enumerating over the list in the for loop:

```
for word in words:
    pass // do something
```

You have already accessed the element in the list and stored it in `word`.

As such, `word[0]` in your loop would be accessing the first element in your word tuple which is not what you'd like to do.

Instead, you'd like to access `word[2]` in your tuple, so something like this should work:

```
first_list = [(0, 'Gallery', 'PROPN', 'nsubj'), (1, 'unveils', 'VERB', 'root'), (2, 'interactive', 'ADJ', 'amod')]

second_list = [(0, 'A', 'DET' 'det'), (1, 'Christmas' , 'PROPN', 'compound'), (2, 'tree' ,'NOUN', 'nsubjpass')]

def print_word_pos(words):
    for word in words:
        print(word[2])

print_word_pos(first_list)
print_word_pos(second_list)
```

Another thing is that you should not be naming your lists as `list` since `list` is a reserved python keyword and might (will) cause conflict later down the line.

Now if the first two lists were combined, you'd want to loop over each list and then for each word in that list, print out the part of speech.

```
def print_word_pos(list_of_words):
    for words in list_of_words:
        for word in words:
            print(word[2])
```

Comment: How do I define the first, second, third list etc...?

Right now, the lists are defined like this:

`for sent in sentences:
    doc = nlp(sent)
    sent_pred = [(token.i, token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_.lower(), token.head.i, token.head.text, token.head.pos_, token.ent_iob_) for token in doc]`

And I'm not sure how to access the n:th list. If I write 
`print(sent_pred)`
I only get the first list

Also, I apologize for the formatting, I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: what you'd want to do is have some new list outside of your for loop. Then instead of `print(sent_pred)` you'd want to append your `sent_pred` to that list. Afterward, you can run the loop in my answer over that list

Comment: I appreciate the help, it worked now.

Answer (score 1):

```
word= [[(0, 'Gallery', 'PROPN', 'nsubj'), (1, 'unveils', 'VERB', 'root'), (2, 'interactive', 'ADJ', 'amod')],[(0, 'A', 'DET' 'det'), (1,'Christmas' , 'PROPN', 'compound'), (2, 'tree' ,'NOUN', 'nsubjpass')]]

[j[2] for i in word for j in i]
```

==> Outputs ['PROPN', 'VERB', 'ADJ', 'DETdet', 'PROPN', 'NOUN']

```
[j[1] for i in word for j in i]
```

==> Outputs ['Gallery', 'unveils', 'interactive', 'A', 'Christmas', 'tree']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: List comprehension solution was always going to be the best way to go. Clever.

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
all_my_lists= [
    [(0, 'Gallery', 'PROPN', 'nsubj'), (1, 'unveils', 'VERB', 'root'), (2, 'interactive', 'ADJ', 'amod')],
    [(0, 'A', 'DET' 'det'), (1, 'Christmas' , 'PROPN', 'compound'), (2, 'tree' ,'NOUN', 'nsubjpass')]
]

for my_list in all_my_lists:
    for tup in my_list:
        print(tup[2])
```

First loop iterate every sublist in my_lists list.

Second loop iterate over each tuple(the collection with '(,)' brackets.
i.e tuple = (0, 'Gallery', 'PROPN', 'nsubj')
and prints the third element.

Comment: I tried this and this also worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

`for sub_list_temp in list:

```
for temp_tuple in sub_list_temp:

    print(temp_tuple[2])
```

`